# Is it possible to put a cdkDrag inside a mat-select?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, angular-cdk

I have a simple [`mat-select`](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) element:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

where in the TypeScript, `foods` is:

```
  foods: Food[] = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];
```

Is it possible use [`cdkDrag`](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview) inside a mat-select element?  I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food">
    <div cdkDropList>
      <div *ngFor="let food of foods">
        <span cdkDragHandle>$$$</span>
        <mat-option [value]="food.value" cdkDrag>
          {{food.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
      </div>
     </div>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

but I'm having trouble getting the dropdown items to drag.  Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!  It is possible:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food" multiple>
    <div cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value" cdkDrag>
        {{food.viewValue}}
        <span cdkDragHandle>$$$</span>
      </mat-option>
      </div>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

It looks like the trick is to wrap your `mat-option`s inside a `cdkDropList` `div`, so that the drop event (`cdkDropListDropped`) will fire reliably. 
 [Working StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p2n73c?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.html).